# unable to create schedule queries in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to restrict a bigquery so that users can only access a specific datasets, i did so without any issues, but why user is not able to create scheduled queries? it is saying to enable api and only project
owner can able to schedule queries , is there anyway to add permissions to create a custom role so that users can query,create and schedule queries ?

//dinesh

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the person creating the transfer has the following required permissions in BigQuery:

- **bigquery.transfers.update** permissions to create the transfer
- **bigquery.datasets.update** permissions on the target dataset

The **bigquery.admin** predefined Cloud IAM role includes **bigquery.transfers.update** and **bigquery.datasets.update** permissions. You should check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions) and the Cloud IAM roles in BigQuery to see the [Predefined roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

Comment: i have already enabled the above said permissions along with the basic data view permissions, the user can able to run the queries and see the data, but unable to schedule the queries, also when the user clicks on enable scheduling it is asking for enabling the bq data transfer api which is already enabled in the cloud project

Comment: @dineshachanta, can you try [create a scheduled query trough CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) with both methods: 'bq query' and 'bq mk' using the user affected?
If you have any error, please share with us.